# Oracle SQL Developer 17.2 Says Executing Script, but no result appears

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running SQL script in Oracle SQL Developer (Version 17.2.0.188), usually SELECT scripts, however nowadays, wherever I hit Ctrl+Enter, SQL Developer says: **"Executing `<the script>` in 0 seconds"** and nothing appears as a result.

I have tried Right Clicking on 'Query Result' and clicked 'Close All'. After that DB reconnects and then the query works, but this takes time.

Another option is to restart the Oracle SQL Developer afresh, but again this is a even more time taking workaround.

Can anyone please suggest what the issue could be and how can I get rid it?

Comment: That version is 3 years old. Try upgrading to 20.2 or 19.4

Comment: Unfortunately the software is governed by the organization and I don't have the privilege to upgrade it. Do know anyway I can have this resolved in this version only?

Comment: Scripts are executed with F5, Ctrl enter is for a single statement

Comment: So basically, I am executing a single script only and that's why use that Key Combination. I have also tried with F5, but same thing happens..